# How to attach a header with the token(which changes with each request) in to all outgoing requests from an api in node.js

Tags: node.js, httprequest

```
var request = require('request');

// Set the headers
var headers = {
    'User-Agent':       'Super Agent/0.0.1',
    'Content-Type':     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

// Configure the request
var options = {
    url: 'http://samwize.com',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
    qs: {'key1': 'xxx', 'key2': 'yyy'}
}

// Start the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Print out the response body
        console.log(body)
    }
})
```

In addition to the above headers, How can I attach a header which can have a token (token expires every 10 minutes) in every request. Like inetercepting every outgoing request, getting the new token and adding it to header.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function called getOptions, or something like that, so each time a request is created the function is called and headers are created as needed.

```
var createToken = function() {
    // Can be generated based on date/time.
    return 'token'; 
}

var getOptions = function() {
    var headers = {
        'User-Agent':       'Super Agent/0.0.1',
        'Content-Type':     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Token': createToken();
    };

    return {
        url: 'http://samwize.com',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
        qs: {'key1': 'xxx', 'key2': 'yyy'}
    };
}
```

And whenever you call request you do:

```
// Start the request
request(getOptions(), function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Print out the response body
        console.log(body)
    }
})
```

Comment: can we add it as a middleware instead of adding the function in every request. I am trying tocreate a middleware like SpringBeanAutoConfiguration in java

Comment: You might be able to, I've never written my own custom Express middleware, but it may be possible.